# Decomposing (unimodular) matrix over integers into product of matrices mod d

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, integers, general-linear-group

If I have a $n\times n$ unimodular matrix $A \in \text{GL}(n,\mathbb Z)$, i.e., with elements $A_{ij} \in \mathbb Z$, is there some way to decompose the matrix into a product of matrices $A=A^{(1)}A^{(2)} \dots A^{(k)}$ such that each $A^{(l)}$ has elements $(A^{(l)}_{ij}-d/2 )\mod d= A^{(l)}_{ij}$, whereby $d$ is an even integer.

For example, if the matrix $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix with elements such that $\max_{i,j} A_{ij}\le K$  and $\min_{i,j} A_{ij}\ge -K$, we could write $A$ in terms of $k$ matrices whereby each matrix $A^{(l)}$ has elements with values $\max_{i,j} A^{(l)}_{ij}\le d/2$  and $\min_{i,j} A^{(l)}_{ij}\ge -d/2$.

Comment: How can $(x - d / 2) \bmod d = x$ hold for any $x$?

Comment: @PinkRabbit I mean that the matrices $A^{(l)}$ have values only between -d/2 and d/2. I have added a clarification